# VBA Code: How to Copy Rows & Create Sheets based on column data From MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA and want copy rows of the following worksheet based on the value of column **OFFICE**:
[image]

So if you notice that there are 10 rows having 4 types of office: Office-A, Office-B, Office-C, Office-D (and so on,it could be more office types ).So i want a VBA code that dynamically creates as many new sheets based on number of types of office in OFFICE column and move the rows that matched with a corresponding office type into new sheet.For: here it will look at column OFFICE and create 4 new sheets, because there 4 types of data and move corresponding  rows to these sheets.Please help me to do that.Thanks

Comment: Have you written any code to try implement the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, dataRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Offices").UsedRange '<--| change "Offices" with your actual sheet name
        Set dataRng = .Cells
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
            .Value = .Parent.Columns("B").Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
            With .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
                For Each cell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                    AddSheet cell.Value
                    With dataRng
                        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(cell.Value).Cells(1, 1)
                    End With
                Next cell
            End With
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            .Clear
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddSheet(shtName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then Worksheets.Add.Name = shtName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @user3598756, it worked in creating different sheets.But Now How to move rows to corresponding sheets.Thanks

Comment: @user5005768 did you go through it?

Comment: Thanks @user3598756, it worked for that file.I am trying with some other variations with different column.still facing problem.thanks

Comment: you are welcome. Since I fulfilled the _specific_ question please mark the answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: sorry @user3598756, i'll

Answer (score 1):

This will create a new sheet for unique data in `column B` and rename the sheet to the cell value. You may have to adapt the code to suit your purpose.

```
Sub dave()

Dim dicKey, dicValues, data, lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
     data = Range("B2:B" & lastrow) ' load data into variable
             With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
                         If .Exists(data(i, 1)) = False Then
                            dicKey = data(i, 1) 'set the key
                            dicValues = data(i, 1) 'set the value for data to be stored
                            .Add dicKey, dicValues
                            Set wsDest = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))
                             wsDest.Name = data(i, 1)
                            Sheets(data(i, 1)).Cells(1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                         End If
                      Next i
              End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @KyloRen, However  i try to run it and it shows error `Run-Time error: '9' Subscript out of range` how to solve it

Comment: Thanks @KyloRen, Still i got `run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error`.

Comment: Thanks @KyloRen,Now it worked in creating different sheets.But Now How to move rows to corresponding sheets.Thanks

Comment: After `Sheets.Add.Name = data(i, 1)` you can just add code to copy the rows. What rows are you trying to copy?

Comment: Thanks @KyloRen, I want copy rows into the sheets that match Office Type.

Comment: OK, I redid the code, try this. You will need to adapt the code to suit your copy convention.